# Why in Firefox border bottom in some TDs/TRs are fatter?

Tags: html, css

In Firefox, why are bottom borders in some `<td>` and `<tr>` elements fatter? In Chrome and Opera, it works well.

```css
table.mytable td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>11111</td>
    <td>11111</td>
    <td>11111</td>
    <td>11111</td>
    <td>11111</td>
    <td>11111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/txfmX.png

After first, fifth and ninth TRs border bottom are fatter.

If I use attribute border=1 in tag table it works just as bad.

Edit: In Firefox I have 100% size/zoom screen.

Comment: Probably subpixel problems. Looks OK on Firefox for Ubuntu

Comment: maybe you have some zoom set in the browser

Comment: check out my answer, if its goes right I'm write an explanation

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't match what your code here produces.

Comment: Works on my Firefox (Win 10)

Comment: I think you are missing **table.mytable{ border-collapse: collapse; }** try and then check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet. I hope this will help you. I have checked on **Firefox** its working fine on (Windows-10)

```css
table.mytable{
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.mytable td {
 border: 1px solid black; 
}
```

```html
<table class="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>11111</td>
    <td>11111</td>
    <td>11111</td>
    <td>11111</td>
    <td>11111</td>
    <td>11111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
    <td>111111</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Still trs are faster, but if I change zoom to 80% then trs are same.

Comment: can you share whole **css** which you write for **this table**? @pofuy